# Refactoring / Re-engineering a large system

Tags: java, architecture, refactoring

I am currently in the process of re-engineering a system which is written in struts 1.3 / PostgreSQL and Hibernate.

The system is architecture'd as an MVC system with presentation logic in JSP's / Actions having View Logic and EJB's having Business logic.

They have used Hibernate as a mapping layer,but some areas still use JDBC functions which have large number of business logic written inside them

The system has about 800k lines of code.

Though the initial idea had been to have only view based logics in action classes and JSP's, there is huge amount of business logic also in the Actions and JSP's.

The database columns are having ambiguous  and duplicated columns as with each requirement, the columns have just been added. This has a nasty effect on the application when picking data, the same data item in two different reports may show different values.

There are no JUnit test cases and documentation is moderate.

In some areas I have managed to remove the business logic out of JSP's / Action tier and bring them to EJB tier.

However my question is where would be the ideal place to start the refactoring,

is it first refactoring the code in JSP's / Actions then move to EJB's for re-engineering logics and finally move to DB?

Or is to start from the DB, refactor the DB then come up the stack?

Is start at the enterprise business logic layer and refactor the business logic?

Where should I start and what should my approach be. I am now going through Martin Fowler's books and lot of articles on refactoring and re-engineering. But I would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: At a recent consulting gig, I had to endure a similar situation but on a different technology stack. I can recommend Michael Feathers' 'Working effectively with Legacy Code'

Comment: I've removed the `postgresql` tag, as Pg isn't really relevant here, it's just a technology that happens to be used. Should really close-vote as too broad, but meh.

Comment: "There are no JUnit test cases and documentation is moderate." That is the first thing that has to be fixed. You need guarantees that after the rebuild is done, the application still does exactly what it is supposed to do. You can't do that if the original application isn't strictly documented, especially all interfaces that are involved.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by adding unit tests.  I would use these to ensure that what worked still works after you refactor it.  This will allow you to take on more significant changes.

I would also focus on the area which you intend to work on anyway.  Improve the testability and design of these sections of code as you work on them. i.e. make this part of the functional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - good luck.

The application size, at 800KLOC,  is non-trivial, so you need to come up with a way of partitioning the approach.

First question would be "what is the purpose of refactoring?". Have you reached the point where the maintainability of the application is unmanageable, and fixing one bug simply exposes 3 others? Do you want to extend the application, and have you found it too expensive? Is application performance suffering?

I ask this because with such a large project, it's important to make sure your approach solves the actual problem you face. For instance, if you decide to start writing unit tests for the entire application, it may not help you with performance issues until much later. If you move the business logic out of the view layer, it may not help much with adding new features.

Once you know what the goals are, define objective, and ideally measurable, criteria to tell you that you've achieved them. For instance, "unit test coverage > 80%"; "no methods with cyclomatic complexity over 7", "code review coverage > 80%". Use automatic code analysis tools (as Namal Dinesh Ubhayawa suggests, Sonar is pretty good), code review tools (we use [Crucible](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview)), and a task tracking solution (we use [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)) - glue these together so you can see whether the project is going in the right direction. I'm a big fan of [information radiators](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Information+radiator) to show at a glance what's going on.

You will need a branching/merging strategy for your re-engineering project - and you may as well make it the one you will use to evolve the project once your re-engineering is complete. I'd invest in [Continous Delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) while you're at it - the immediate feedback you get from building, deploying and testing the app is hugely valuable.

Next question is "is there a logical structure to the application, either in the technology solution or the business domain?". You've got a horizontal partitioning from the MVC architecture - is there a vertical partitioning? Again, as Namal Dinesh Ubhayawa suggests, picking a manageable, self-contained subset of the application, and working through that module top to bottom will quickly show whether you're on the right track.

Once you've agreed the module you're going to work on, create a release plan. Set yourself a target, and use whatever development process you've got to work towards that target. Make the target as specific as you can:

> The team will release a new version of the product information module by 15 February. The release will meet our quality criteria of 0 P1 defects, < 5 P2 defects, and < 15 lower priority defects. Unit test coverage will be x, code review coverage will be y. No methods will have a cyclomatic complexity > z. There will be no business logic in the view layer, and the data model will be normalized to 3rd normal form".

Track your progress against this goal - given the size of your application, you will need several releases, and understanding how much you can get done in given time period will help you to plan.

Finally - ask yourself how the application go to the state it's in. What are the root causes? Consider using the [5 whys protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys). Very often, I find that poor application design and implementation is a side effect of non-technical pressures. If the business says "we don't care about quality, just get it done", you end up with poor code, no matter how good the developers. If you don't remove that pressure, your refactoring/reengineering project may well fail.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all who took time to support me by answering the above. I know it is a bit late but I believe I need to explain the process and the path I took.

- Identify the key operational / functional areas of the system
- Made sure that I have automated functional testing with Selenium test suite
- Made sure that the system can be deployed with automation using Jenkins
- Break the system is macro level sub systems according to operational areas where each sub system can be tested / built and released using Jenkins
- Started breaking the macro sub systems as micro services (used Spring Cloud / Spring Boot / Eureka Service Registry / Zuul / SideCar etc..)
- Started removing he EJB's
- Upgraded the technology stack in each service as we broke off the services
- Started segmenting the database using PostgreSQL itself

Right now we are in the database segmentation process and we still have more services to create and clean, but things have tremendously improved thus far. If anyone needs more info on our architectural decisions, design considerations or challenges we faced please send me a mail and I will give whatever information I can give.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to divide your application feature/module wise and re-factor module wise. For example 
    user-registration module
    Search module 
    reporting module 
    security and etc.
Prior to start refactoring you should know the current implementation business logic clearly and big picture.  Also it will make your effort easy if you can 
1. Use Jprofiler or Your Tool kit to profile you application. This is track calling path , identify long running methods
2. Integrate current code base with Sonar to find code level issues. http://www.sonarqube.org/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider re-writing it from scratch using the latest version of Struts/JSP rather than attempting to clean up the existing code. 
1: I'd start with deciding if you want to stay with PostgreSQL or some other database first. Example question to ask is: If your company already has a database such as Oracle that it pays for and maintains, you may want to switch over to it.
2:Next, get your DBA to rewrite the database from scratch correctly with normalization, indexes, foreign key constraints, views, stored procedures, etc as much as possible. He doesn't have to rewrite the entire schema at once. He can start with the major tables you need at the beginning of your project and add more tables as you move onto the next coding task(s). This task is for someone well versed in database design and not for Java developers. Your database is the foundation that stays around long after your web application has been replaced in time or morphed into something else. It needs to be correct.
3:Migrate some or most of the data from the old database to the new database, without violating the added constrants on the new database. Store the migration script somewhere so it can be re-run periodically.
4: Write a database layer using Hibernate. There are utilities that will analyize the database schema and write Hibernate for you rather than by hand. Forbid anyone from using raw JDBC. Hibernate uses caching/lazy loading. JDBC will interfer with that (dirty read issues, etc).
5: Analize the business logic/JSP pages to determine the business rules its trying to accomplish and create your own code. Don't port the old code over line for line since its probably incomplete/ poorly thought through.